# Contacting developer of QGIS plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I want to give feedback to the developer of a non-core QGIS plugin.

(Numerical Vertex Edit by Cedric Moeri, who seems to have no webpage for his plugins)

I joined OSGeo Wiki but hardly know my way around it, or whether that is a good place to start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a plugin page at http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/numericalVertexEdit/

That provides link to bug reporting and other tools (via SourceForge and Trac). For example:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/geoing/report/1

There is a way to send messages direct to a user via SourceForge, but please consider whether that is really appropriate. If in any doubt, a bug report or feature suggestion is probably more appropriate.

Comment: Ok, I'll follow your suggestion. Thanks for the links.